# SQL Count - some correct values, some incorrect values

Tags: sql, count

I am using COUNT(ScoreID) as scoreCount to display the number of Scores a property has in a vote.

Is there any reason at all why the results would sometimes display the correct value, but other display an incorrect value?

I have noticed that for some, if I add a new record to the scores table, the output on the page using the COUNT(ScoreID) as scoreCount is sometimes correct, and at others wrong - usually by multiples of the correct figure.

So for example, I can have two results:

```
Count(Lodge A) | Count(Lodge B)       /* Correct for B not for A , A should show 10  */
30 votes       | 30 votes
```

If I add a new vote to Lodge A, and a new vote to Lodge B in the table, that output changes to:

```
Count(Lodge A) | Count(Lodge B)       /* Correct for B not for A , A should show 11  */
33 votes       | 31 votes
```

Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: You have an incomplete join multiplying your rowcounts. Please supply the complete query, along with complete DDL with indices for all tabled

Comment: Also tell us which DBMS you are using? Oracle? Postgres?